# position a view horizontally center and vertically at bottom in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes

I have a container view that has child views in storyboard

I would like to position the container view horizontally center and vertically at bottom.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Click on your child view, then ctrl+drag to your parent view twice. Fitst time to the top and then left. Each time select what you want. Then ctrl+drag to its own twice and select heigt and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make it center X to super view and bottom space 0 to bottom layout guide.It could like this:
[image]

Double click the bottom space and change the view bottom to center Y:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two constraint for this

One is Align centre x , that is for horizontally centre

and second is bottom space to you view.